# gradient on Gingerbread

Tags: android, gradient, android-2.3-gingerbread

**Updated**
I have a problem with gradient bitmaps on android 2.3. I read this [great article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/) and decode my bitmaps using next options:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = true;
```

And on android 2.2 everything is great, but on android 2.3 gradient artifacts remain even after that decoding.

I run [application from article](http://www.curious-creature.org/data/BitmapConfig.zip) on 2.3 with my bitmaps and all variants are <s>bad: 16/32 bit, (not) dither and RBG_565, ARGB_8888 and ARGB_4444 - gradient has artifacts. Also I tried to decode without options.</s> Everything is ok. Sorry, problem was in

```
opts.inScaled=true;
opts.inDensity=100;
opts.inTargetDensity=800;
```

---

*But* now I need to make working this code on android 2.3 and its still produce bad gradient (on android 2.2 everything is ok):

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tabsImage);
    // decode bitmaps
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    options.inDither = true;
    Bitmap tabImageOn = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mainActivity.getResources(), tabImageResourceOnId, options);
    Bitmap tabImageOff = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mainActivity.getResources(), tabImageResourceOffId, options);
    // create new selector
    StateListDrawable tabImage = new StateListDrawable();
    tabImage.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected }, new BitmapDrawable(mainActivity.getResources(), tabImageOn));
    tabImage.addState(new int[] {}, new BitmapDrawable(mainActivity.getResources(), tabImageOff));
    tabImage.setDither(true);
    // set selector to tab
    imageView.setImageDrawable(tabImage);
```

I tried to set window pixel format in `onCreate`/before/after that method next way:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

But nothing has been changed (it's gingerbread, it's using 32 bit window format).

Why do so behaviour appear and how can i solve my problem?

Thanks. Good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with moving drawables to `hdpi` folder.