# Android gradient NEVER works (always banding)

Tags: android, gradient, radial-gradients

I tried to add a (radial) gradient as background (in Android 4.0), either as background image or programmatically but none of them never works. I can only test it in emulator, but I guess it's the same on a 4.0 device.

These solutions don't work:

- Placing in raw folder.
  ([Disable Android resource / image / png optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929884/disable-android-resource-image-png-optimization))
- Making a proxy xml with dithering and anti aliasing true, as well as saving opacy of png to 99%. ([android:dither="true" does not dither, what's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769885/androiddither-true-does-not-dither-whats-wrong))
- Overriding onAttachedToWindow ([Android: Using linear gradient as background looks banded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928101/android-using-linear-gradient-as-background-looks-banded))
- Moving to hdpi folder ([gradient on Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746166/gradient-on-gingerbread))
- Making gradient programmatically (http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/high-quality-radial-gradient-in-android/)

I guess I tried some more things but maybe someone has an idea how to build a working gradient as background?

My current code looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_string"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and background_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_portrait" />
```

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: It's still banding in this example. Moreover I can't even create a radial gradient because of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: radius must be > 0` although I've set a radius (example bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it's just the emulator. On a real device it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link mate, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient.html

override on draw function to draw circle using canvas object