# How to get a smooth gradient

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, gradient

I want to get a gradient background but it gives me color banding. 
How do i get a smooth gradient?

this is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="@color/black"
        android:endColor="@color/top_background_home"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

```
android:background="@drawable/background_home"
```

Comment: Plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android

Comment: This is a other question cause I know how to make a gradient but there is color banding and i want to get rid of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android gradient NEVER works (always banding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985385/android-gradient-never-works-always-banding)